# Transforming coordinates from one projection to another

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

```
var bounds = config.init_center.transform( new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31466"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"));

    console.log(config.init_center);
    console.log(bounds);
```

I have coordinates from a map that uses projection epsg:31466 and want to show then on a map with coordinates epsg:3857.

I would expect that the output of the two console logs given above would turn out to be different, since a transformation took place. However, they do NOT differ. They are exactly the same.

What is wrong with my assumption?

Comment: Have you defined EPSG:31466 somewhere? Openlayers only knows a few definitions, and needs proj4js for the rest. Not as comfortable as real proj4...

Comment: Ah, thank you. What do I need to do in order to get proj4js?

Comment: Visit http://proj4js.org/. And you have to define the projection 31466.

Comment: Ok, but how do I 'define' the projection 31466? The only thing I have found so far is something like this: `Proj4js.defs['EPSG:31466'] = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6+k=1.000000+x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs';`

Comment: without any explaination. And this site: http://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/proj4js/trunk/lib/defs/ does not contain any information to 31466.

Comment: Still, if I use `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.3/proj4-src.js"></script>`, I get `Proj4js is not defined`, for `Proj4js.defs['EPSG:31466'] = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6+k=1.000000+x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs';`

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13499/how-do-i-include-proj4js-in-openlayers

Comment: no, that's a different one. already seen.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this (change GeoJSON to the format you want to load.):

```
vector_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
    'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31466"),
    'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857")
});

result = vector_format.read(newFeatures);
vectorLayer.addFeatures(result);
```

This worked for me.